# Wordpress static pages: how to embed content into templates?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to convert a primarily static site to wordpress to see how easy it is for the site owner to make changes to the pages. I've copied everything to the Theme folder and created the header and footer templates, and the preview looks fine. I then went on to create a new page and add some content (Pages/Add New) and attached a template to the page (Attribute/Template dropdown). My question is how does the content entered into a new or edited page get embeded into the selected template?

Any help gratefully accepted, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static page can be edited by the site owner inside of Wordpress. Are you missing the loop in your template pages? Nothing entered in the wordpress editor will end up on a static page unless the WP loop is in the template file:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>  //this is how the content shows up

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Read [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) and [Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I thought the loop was just for posts as the Loop specifically does a while(have_posts()... and nowhere in the docs, or on the web, could I find a simple example as you have shown, to display a static page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is...

1. Goto wordpress admin
2. Create a new page
3. Go into HTML mode in the WP text editor
4. Paste your HTML in there.

You may need to tweak some of your HTML to get it displaying properly. Things like relative links will need to be changes.

Comment: Adding the HTML isn't a problem, it's how to get your html displayed if the page is attached to a template?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You have a wordpress template and you want to show some static HTML inside that wordpress template? If that's not the case, you'll have to explain the problem better.

Comment: Let's put it this way, I have set up a theme containing bunch of static pages which have identical header and footer, so I've created header and footer templates. How do I set up each static page so it includes the header and footer templates and the content is editable via WP? My thinking is that the site owner can use this system to make occasional changes to the 'static' page text, but if there's a better way to do it, please let me know? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML within the wordpress text editor but there are some things it won't recognize. However, any php or other programming has to be put in the template page or called in through a plugin/widget for it to work.