# How to insert a static page in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I have WP instance installed on hosting. I also have one static HTML page in its own folder with some graphic files that I want to use as landing page for the site. I don't want to insert it as WP page or anything like that, want to keep it simple. I have also permalinks configured. So I can't access the page just by going to `www.mysite.com/landingpage/index.html` now. Is there a simple way to make the static page accessible inside WordPress instance?

Answer (score 2):

For each page, create a template, with the static text you want, the query for the category you want to display, and a copy of index.php of your theme.

Some links you may like to see.

- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/creating-a-static-page-that-displays-posts
- http://moshublog.com/2007/09/10/static-frontpage-combined-with-dynamic-content/
- [Wordpress static pages: how to embed content into templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620390/wordpress-static-pages-how-to-embed-content-into-templates)

Good luck..  :-)